# Why when we study spherically symmetric objects we don't use the Einstein equations with cosmological constant?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmological-constant

I'm wondering why when we study spherically symmetric objects  we neglect the existence of the cosmological constant. His contribution is just to small for "small" scales?

I mean, for a spherically symmetric objects usually  we use the schwarzschild and the Einstein equations
$$G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{3} T_{\mu\nu}$$
but not the "full" equations
$$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{3} T_{\mu\nu}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [De Sitter-Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric) describes a black hole with no charge and no angular momentum in a spacetime with a cosmological constant.

The observed value of the cosmological constant is so small that it is essentially irrelevant to the geometry near a non-cosmologically-sized black hole.

Comment: The question was probably interested in whether there might be a phase transition that would introduce a qualitative difference even for the smallest possible $\Lambda$ value? Is there some general way to rule this out?

Comment: @Kagaratsch A phase transition in *what*?

Comment: Perhaps a phase transition in the solution to the equations of motion, and with it in e.g. Ricci scalar curvature? Which would not reduce back to Schwarzschild delta function value in the limit $\Lambda\to0$.

Comment: @Kagaratsch The Wikipedia article has the scalar curvature. You can determine whether it has some characteristic that you could convincingly call a phase transition.

Comment: @Kagaratsch I get $R=4\Lambda$, just like for De Sitter space. It would be hard to argue that a constant has a phase transition.

Comment: I see, so explicitly solving for the result shows that it does continuously reduce to the Schwarzschild case in the limit, which means there is no phase transition.

Comment: @Kagaratsch: If you are indeed interested in *phase transitions* that may occur in black hole spacetimes with “varying” cosmological constant I recommend looking at the review [Black hole chemistry:  thermodynamics with Lambda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06147). (I do not think that this is the viewpoint OP is asking about, so I won't be writing an answer).